# how to resolve gredle error after update android gredle plugin version and gradle version in android studio project structure?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

i update my android project gradle plugin version to 7.0.2 and gradle version to 6.9.1
but after applay i get some error like below:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'HozorGhiyab'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find transform-api-2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.build:transform-api:2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/transform-api/2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api/transform-api-2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api.jar
   > Could not find jetifier-processor-1.0.0-beta09.jar (com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta09).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/jetifier/jetifier-processor/1.0.0-beta09/jetifier-processor-1.0.0-beta09.jar
   > Could not find jetifier-core-1.0.0-beta09.jar (com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-core:1.0.0-beta09).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/jetifier/jetifier-core/1.0.0-beta09/jetifier-core-1.0.0-beta09.jar

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

how can i fix this errors?
thanks